# Is it possible to produce a report matrix as a result set in sql query given a singe database table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Given the following SQL table:

```
GroupAvailable, GroupAssigned, Title
----------------------------------------
GroupA,GroupA,Widget1
GroupA,GroupB,Widget1
GroupB,GroupA,Widget1
```

Need a report to look like:

```
Widget1
               GroupA     GroupB

GroupA           X          X
GroupB           X


Widget2
etc.
```

Is this possible to do in query? Or something pretty close? Or would a combination of code and sql be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function will get you close to the result:

```
select name, 
  coalesce(GroupA, '') GroupA, 
  coalesce(GroupB, '') GroupB
from
(
  select title +' '+ groupavailable name,
    groupassigned,
    'X' as flag
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(flag)
  for groupassigned in (GroupA, GroupB)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56641/1).

If you have an unknown number of groups, then you could use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(GroupAvailable) 
                    from yourtable 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(GroupAvailable)+', '''') as '+QUOTENAME(GroupAvailable)
                    from yourtable 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT name,' + @colsNull + ' 
            from 
            (
                select title +'' ''+ groupavailable name,
                  groupassigned,
                  ''X'' as flag
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(flag)
                for groupassigned in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56641/6)

Both versions will give a result:

```
|           NAME | GROUPA | GROUPB |
------------------------------------
| Widget1 GroupA |      X |      X |
| Widget1 GroupB |      X |        |
| Widget2 GroupB |      X |        |
```

Comment: +1 - With the caveat that you need to hard-code the list of new field names.  To do it dynamically, you need dynamically generated sql code.

Comment: @MatBailie Very true, I was in the process of writing a dynamic version which I have now added to my answer. :)

Comment: Does sp_execute_sql have any merrit here?  As it will cache the execution plan for queries generated with the same columns?

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, you can use `sp_executesql` to get the result. Here is a demo with that code -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56641/11